# Why are they singing in Les Misérables 2012 film?

Tags: les-miserables

When I watched the movie Les Misérables (2012), I was surprised to see them singing! It looks funny to me. The story is excellent and touching but I find it quite inappropriate to see them singing. I feel like watching and opera show, not a movie, and I don't even like opera.

I have seen many animations where singing is very common. For cartoons and animations, singing is very matching because it is mostly designed for kids and for entertainment. I have seen other movies like [Enchanted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enchanted_%28film%29) where they sing a lot but it is very matching with the beautiful scenery, dress and the beautiful actors. But the movie Les Misérables is not like that. People are very dirty, the places are dirty, there is only death and struggles. And they are singing :( I think it should be done like a normal movie instead of the actors singing always. I also don't like the way they sing. It is only spoiling the movie.

Why was  Les Misérables (2012) movie made in musical style? Would it be better if it was done like a **normal movie**, which I think will make it **more real and more touching**?

Comment: The obvious answer would be that the movie was most probably based on the famous musical *Les Miserables*. Yet I sense a not so bad question hidden under all the subjective opinions here.

Comment: My understanding was the producers wanted this to *be* the opera, only with the grandeur only a movie can provide. *Les Misérables* (the opera) is, well, an opera. *Almost* all dialogue is sung. This is why all dialogue is sung in the movie. If you don't like the singing, there are many movie versions which do not include or where not all dialogue is sung. I mean, if you don't want to hear them sing, don't go to an opera. Personally, if I never hear Hugh Jackman sing again, it will be too soon.

Comment: @Paulster2 Do you like the opera?

Comment: No. I do like the story behind *Les Mis* though. I am still perplexed by why everyone thought Hugh Jackman's singing was so great ... I thought Russell Crowe did a much better job ... but this is JMHO. The only way I would routinely watch Opera was if I was a paid critic, but then I wouldn't have that job in the first place because nobody would like my opinions of them. (*Do any of us really like paid critics opinions though?*)

Comment: @Paulster2 As a side note, if you like the story, then I might recommend the French 4-part made for TV movie with *Gerard Depardieu* and *John Malkowitch* from the 2000s. While I don't know the source material, I really enjoyed that (though, I also liked this 2012 musical film, and *Russel Crowe* was great).

Comment: @ChristianRau ... Thanks for the recommend ... but I'm good. ;-)

Comment: @ChristianRau '*Russel Crowe*' was great' ?!?! [Controversial](http://whatculture.com/film/15-most-awkward-moments-in-film-history.php/3), Christian, ha ha! we had 5 walk-outs at my cinema in the first week, and 3 of them were attributed to [Russell Crowe](http://www.thehollywoodgossip.com/2012/12/les-miserables-review-russell-crowe-ruins-everything/)!

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional Wow. But Ok, I'm not a big music or acting expert anyway, maybe I just liked his voice (since I'm normally used to dubbing). But I enjoyed his presence in every scene (well, there wasn't really anyone who annoyed me there, no, not even *Amanda Seyfreid*).

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional Maybe if *Crowe* had sung better, who knows if I had liked him so much or found him so (positively) unique, hehe. Sometimes you can't change what your heart (uh wait, let's rather say ears) reacts to, hehe. ;-)

Answer (score 10):

The story has already been shot as a normal movie, back in 1998. And 1995. And 1982. And 1978.... on and on and on.

The 1998 [version](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119683/) of Les Miserables was a straight take on the Victor Hugo novel, intended to be a po faced English language interpretation of the failed second revolution. It was well received (still rated 78% fresh by Rotten Tomatoes) but did not meet anywhere near the same level of financial success as the 2013 version.

The new version was created as a musical because this is the first time the story has been told in musical format in a feature film, having been adapted from the long running stage show. The Musical had already proven its popularity, being the [longest running stage show](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Mis%C3%A9rables_%28musical%29) on the West End of all time.

There have been **nine** [interpretations of the story](http://stuartfernie.org/Misfilms.htm), but this is the first time *the musical* has been re-created, instead of the story.

Basically, the reason they sing is because that's entirely the point of this production: it is an adaptation of *The Musical*, not the [book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Mis%C3%A9rables).

Comment: I guess I'm watching the wrong version of Les Miserables. :)

Comment: You keep using "musical" ... wouldn't your statements be better served by calling it *opera* ... A musical usually entails music, dialogue, dancing, and singing. Opera is a play (or performance) which is sung. I think it bears differentiation.

Comment: They do have [different meanings](http://www.theguardian.com/theguardian/2011/may/04/difference-between-opera-and-musical), but Les Mis is most definitely *a [Musical](http://www.lesmis.com/)*, not an Opera. Les Miserables actively markets itself as a Musical. And FYI, Opera often contains [dancing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera) too...

Comment: Fair enough ... you definitely know more about the industry than I do, so will leave it up to your interpretation. I don't like either (musical or opera) very well, so I am not an objective critic of the genre.

Comment: @Paulster2, I'm not a fan of them either, but musicals have a heavy legacy in [Film History](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/15803/on-the-decline-of-musicals-in-american-cinema/15826#15826), of which I am an acolyte!... Despite what the professional terminology suggests, I don't believe there to be a huge difference between Opera and Musicals, I think its just market deviation. What's the difference between a Musical and an Opera? £40 a ticket.

Comment: @Paulster2 - It's not entirely market deviation. While there is a fine line, in an opera, the music is the driving force and showcased, and in a musical, the words take more emphasis than the music does. This is one reason that opera can be enjoyed even if you don't understand the language.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I know this is late to the game but if there's actual spoken dialogue, it's not an opera. In opera (at least traditional full operas, not operettas), **everything** is sung. Dancing is irrelevant to opera, though.